# How to cast std::vector<myClass*> to std::vector<const myClass* const>?

Tags: c++

I have a `std::vector<myClass*>` member of a class I would like to give public const-access to in the class interface. To do this I want to be able to write:

```
    class myClass{
        public: 
        myClass() { /*allocate dynamic stuff */};
        virtual ~myClass() { /* delete dynamic stuff */};

        //Accessors
        const std::vector<const myClass * const> members() const{ //<- How do I implement?

            //Compiles Fine - cit iterates over   const int*    objects
            std::vector<myClass*>::iterator it =  _members.begin(); 

            //Does not compile
            std::vector<myClass* const>::const_iterator citc= it;

            //I need citc to iterate over     cosnt int* const     objects - How?
            std::vector<const myClass * const> members_(citc, citc + _members.size());  //Compile Error

            return members_;
        };  
        /* ...moar stuff....*/
        private:
        /* ...moar stuff...*/
        std::vector<myClass*> _members;
    };
```

This code was a *cleaned example* out of context so I have not compiled it, but in the actual code, I deduced from a couple screen lengths of error messages that the only serious problem was that i need the citc iterator to iterate over 'const myClass* const' objects rather than 'const myClass*' objects. Thoughts? Thanks a mil.

Comment: First of all, to clarify: You want to create a copy of the entire vector of pointers, correct? Not just a type-cast in the sense that it still refers to the original object, but under a different type, correct?

Comment: Instead of giving access to the vector itself, give access to iterators into it. Probably want to return const_iterator's using `cbegin` and `cend`.

Comment: @jogojapan Sorry. That IS what i'm trying to do in the code, but a direct type-cast would work as well. Either is fine, whatever is relatively fast and doesn't allow public access to change any the _members vector, what it points to, or change the elements it points to. I hope this helps.

Comment: @JerryCoffin but would giving access to the iterator actually give what I want. from my understanding, returning 'cbegin()' would only give an iterator over 'const myClass*' elements, and I want to only give public access to 'const myClass* const' elements.

Comment: `const myClass *const` means you're returning a const pointer to a const object. This is one of the places that C++'s definition of `const` doesn't really work very well. But returning `const_iterator`s will give the client read-only access to the elements in the vector, which I'd guess is what you probably want.

Comment: _ const myClass *const means you're returning a const pointer to a const object_ - Yes, this was what I intended. But perhaps returning the  `const_iterator ` is good enough. Thanks!

Comment: @user27886: Const-qualifying the pointer you return accomplishes nothing. The user copies that to their own pointer anyway, so they end up with a (non-const) pointer to a const object. The const qualification on the pointer itself is (pardon the pun) pointless.

Comment: Just to avoid misunderstandings: Returning a `const_iterator` is practically equivalent to returning a const-pointer to a non-const object. You cannot use that iterator to change the pointer (i.e. the address) stored in the vector, but you can still use it to change the object behind that address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return std::vector<myClass const *>( _members.begin(), _members.end() );
```

And remove that one `const` from your return value (the 2nd one in the `<>`s).  It does nothing but get in the way.

Comment: So I've been wondering actually... Is there anyway to return an object by reference containing pointers

Comment: @user27886 Returning local objects by reference is undefined behavior: references don't manage lifetimes.